# In Docker Hub, last pulled doesn't correspond with incrementing pull count

Tags: dockerhub

I am trying to get an accurate count of how many times my docker image has been pulled. I frequently see the pulled field resetting to something like '2hrs' ago, but this doesn't correspond do an increment in the pulled count. Is this feature not working or am I misunderstanding something?

image for reference: https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/balzack/databag/general

I've observed this for awhile now, so I don't think it's an issue of them being updated on different schedules. I see the last pulled resetting usually around 10 times before I see count increment once.

Comment: you could try asking docker community directly, I'm sure they have a mailing list or issue tracker on their github

Comment: thanks for the advice. I just posted there now.